# Enumeration as member value or trait for modelling type in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums, data-modeling, traits

Assume that I intercepted network traffic and measured the time, size and type(TCP, UDP, AppleTalk) of each packet. Nothing else like IP adresses or data is measured and should be modelled. Filtering and computing statistics is what I have in mind. I have no intention whatsoever to extend specialise classes for TCP, UDP, ... with extra information or functions. I am new to Scale and wonder what the proper way is.

With enums like in C/C++:

```
object TransportType extends Enumeration {
     type TransportType = Value
     val TCP = Value("TCP")
     val UDP = Value("UDP") 
     val AppleTalk = Value("AppleTalk")

 }

 class Packet(val time:int , val size:Int, val type:TransportType)

 val p1 = new Packet(0, 200, TransportType.UDP)
 val p2 = new Packet(1, 1000, TransportType.TCP)
```

Or with traits:

```
object TransportType {
     trait TCP
     trait UDP
     trait AppleTalk
 }

 class Packet(val time:int , val size:Int)

 val p1 = new Packet(0, 200) with TransportType.UDP
 val p2 = new Packet(1, 1000) with TransportType.TCP
```

In the latter case, there might be packets without a special type. This is not possible in the first case. I am not interested in these modelling differences. I wonder if its advisable to create many traits/classes like in the second solution and use the type system to encode attributes. If the second solution is correct, then assume the Packets have another attribute Origin. Would it be ok to model it like this:

```
object Origin {
     trait NA
     trait SA
     trait EU
     trait Asia
     trait Africa
     trait Australia
 }

 val p1 = new Packet(0, 200) with TransportType.UDP with Origin.Asia
```

Is the second solution the right - the Scala-tic - solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good general approach (with lots of exceptions, reservations and special cases, as all general approaches are), that I would recommend is to look at it this way: members are properties, while traits are behaviors.

If a tcp packet in your model *behaves* differently from udp (for example, one has methods that the other does not, or if there are functions that accept one as argument, but not the other etc.), it should be a trait, otherwise, a property should do (you can still have packets without "special type" if there is a need - just make the property optional, so, that doesn't really matter).